How to hide the "Content Type Field" in a SharePoint Library form - create a new document set
I have a Sharepoint online Library where I'm using a SharePoint default form (with some json) to create a document set and go through an approval process.  Once I've created the Document Set, and re-open the form, the "Content Type" field displays at the bottom.  How can I hide that, while still being able to create the document set?  Turning off "Allow management of content types" removes the ability to create the doc set.
Thanks!
